# How can I populate an encrypted PDF using python?

Tags: python

so I am trying to quicken my workflow by auto populating a pdf using a python library (preferred, all languages accepted). The pdf is from another corporation (that we work with) and is encrypted with 128-bit AES encryption as well as created with:`Adobe LiveCycle Designer ES 10.0`, I can manually input information into the document and even submit it to them using it. I have tried so many libraries, the last being pdfrw, but all of them required the file to be decrypted which would make the file lose its signatures they require (I have contacted them before due to a similar issue, but they **require** them signed or else they wont accept it). Of course the password is not empty (just in case you were wondering). Does anyone have ant ideas on how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Tried Using multiple python libraries, most notably pdfrw.

Comment: If you were edit it by yourself (with no program), it would still be valid, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, no @Axium. I need to use Adobe Acrobat X or DC... Printing and manually filling it out would not be an option (or digitally doing such)

Comment: If you need to use Adobe’s own software, you’ll likely have to control the actual program as I don’t believe there are any libraries that could help you change the PDF directly.

Comment: The thing is, it is a common routine to use Adobe pdfs with python, so much so that there are other questions here even using the same design software. The issue is, mine is encrypted and even though it is not required, all the libraries I tried required it.

Comment: Well, seems to me like any other questions I post, it's gone cold.